# My Shoppe Template Loading Gmail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin Forums and I seem to be having trouble with getting this "My Shoppe" App Template to work as advertised. From the video from the website.  I can see that the feedback messaging process is done via the app. But everytime I attempt to send feedback to the admin app, Gmail will open up for me asking if I want to send an email. Any help or workarounds with this? I have looked all over...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the AzureDataStore: by default it will use the OfflineDataStore, which submits feedback via e-mail.

see https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyShoppe/issues/17